# Google Analytics & IDFA

Tags: ios, google-analytics, app-store-connect, google-analytics-api, idfa

I just submitted an iOS app on iTunesConnect where I recently added Google Analytics. I checked that I do not use the IDFA when asked during the submission process.

According to the Google Analytics changelog, the SDK allows for IDFA collection if the bool is set to true. I am not using Admob, just the analytics platform, so I never touched the bool allowIDFACollection ... so I am hoping that there was no way it was ever set to true, (default is false)

Did I do the right thing?

Apple rejects binaries that have the IDFA in it but where the submitter said that it does not use IDFA

Comment: I've read outdated, unclear, and unanswered versions of this same issue on StackOverflow.... I will be sure to answer my own question in the next 5 days once the app is approved.

Comment: So now I'm doing the same as you, and you didn't answer your question ;)

Comment: So now I'm doing the same as well.. And there is no answer..